# Layout not displayed properly while dynamically loading a listview in Android?

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, android-relativelayout

```
    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/txtBabbleListTitle"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:textColor = "#000000"       
        android:text = "New Babble has been put up." >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/txtBabbleDateTime"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
    android:textColor = "#000000"    
    android:text = "2010-04-10 09:47:42" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/txtBabbleTotalReplies"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
    android:textColor = "#000000"       
        android:text = "(7)" >
   </TextView> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the layout that I am inflating in the Adapter. Everything is displayed, but only the second textview which should be displayed at the bottom is getting displayed at the top. Can someone let me know the problem with this?

I I view this in the layout tab in Eclipse then it displays properly. The problem occurs only when the text is fetched dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't indicate how you are "inflating in the Adapter".

If you are doing that yourself via a `LayoutInflater`, be sure to use `inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false)`, where `R.layout.row` is the layout resource matching the XML you have above, and `parent` is the `ListView` (which is passed into `getView()` or `newView()`, where you are doing the inflation). If you do not use this specific version of the `inflate()` method, `RelativeLayout` will not work well as a row container.

Comment: Thanx a lot. I was inflating using inflate(R.layout.row, null). I changed it to what you suggested and it solved the problem. Thanx again.